# Angular ui router not working in subdirectory

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I using angular ui router to start making my first mean stack application but I have an issue that one of my ui-view works but the same view inside a directory doesn't work.

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

// For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider

     // THIS WORKS
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'indexController'
    })


     // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/login/index.html',
        controller: 'indexController'
    })



$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')

}]);
```

can anybody tell me why when i put my home.html file inside the login directory the ui-view stop rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened I recreated the login folder and now it works.

Comment: do you find out the issue or solution how is it working? I am facing the similar problem.